# Convert a column of lists into binary columns

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

I have an R data frame with a column that looks like this

```
codes
111:222:333
222
111:222
```

I want to expand the `codes` column into individual binary columns like this:

```
111 222 333
1   1   1
0   1   0
1   1   0
```

I tried converting the `codes` column to a list of characters using `strsplit`. Then, I unnested the `codes` column and wanted to perform `pivot_wider`, but it seems like I cannot do that with columns that have duplicate identifying columns.

```
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(codes = strsplit(codes, ":", TRUE))
  unnest(codes) %>%
  mutate(value = 1) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = codes,
                         values_from = value,
                         values_fill = 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `dummy_cols` from `fastDummies`

```
library(fastDummies)
dummy_cols(df1, "codes", split = ":", remove_selected_columns = TRUE)
```

-output

```
  codes_111 codes_222 codes_333
1         1         1         1
2         0         1         0
3         1         1         0
```

NOTE: It may be better to have column names that start with alphabets.  If we want to have only the values

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
dummy_cols(df1, "codes", split = ":", remove_selected_columns = TRUE)  %>% 
  setNames(str_remove(names(.), "codes_"))
   111 222 333
1   1   1   1
2   0   1   0
3   1   1   0
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(codes = c("111:222:333", "222", "111:222")),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach using `separate_rows`:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  mutate(r = 1:n()) %>%
  separate_rows(., codes, sep=":") %>% 
  table %>% 
  t

#   codes
# r   111 222 333
#   1   1   1   1
#   2   0   1   0
#   3   1   1   0
```

Although this will give us a table, so if we need a dataframe we should use `pivot_wider` instead of `table`.

```
df1 %>%
  mutate(r = 1:n(), val = 1) %>%
  separate_rows(., codes, sep=":") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = "codes", values_from = "val", values_fill = 0) %>%
  select(-r)

# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#  `111` `222` `333`
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1    1     1     1
# 2    0     1     0
# 3    1     1     0
```

#### Data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(codes = c("111:222:333","222", "111:222"))
```

Comment: Adding `val` is a genius move.

Answer (score 0):

Add an `id` column to your data.frame before `unnest`

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(codes = strsplit(codes, ":", TRUE)) |>
  mutate(id = row_number()) |>
  unnest(codes) |>
  mutate(value = 1) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = codes,
                         values_from = value,
                         values_fill = 0)


##> + # A tibble: 3 × 4
##>      id `111` `222` `333`
##>   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
##> 1     1     1     1     1
##> 2     2     0     1     0
##> 3     3     1     1     0
```